# Как при отправке писем с сайта, используя Gmail, избавиться от предупреждения: "Возможно, это письмо не было отправлено с адреса"?

Tags: smtp, gmail

Реализовал у себя на сайте отправку писем через smtp используя gmail.

Однако все письма приходят с предупреждением "Возможно, это письмо не было отправлено с адреса ..." или вовсе попадают в спам.

Нашел кучу рекомендаций как избавиться от этого предупреждения, но все они заключаются в том, что нужно завести аккаунт в google apps, но этот сервис стал платным, да и мне не нужна доменная почта, меня вполне устраивает example@gmail.com. Возможно ли, как-то избавиться от предупреждения не регистрируясь в apps, тем более платно, используя простую почту Gmail?

Comment: В заголовке `From` письма у вас указан тот же гугловский адрес, что и на аккаунте с помощью которого почту отправляете?

Comment: да, указываю один и тот же адрес

Comment: какой ты хитрый, надеюсь, невозможно. бери да отправляй через свой сайт

Comment: Покажите все заголовки одного из таких полученных писем.